# Sort Date Year-Month using Panda

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

I have python pandas data frame like the following

**panda data frame**

> ```
> +---------+-------+
> |  Date   | value |
> +---------+-------+
> | 2013-12 | A     |
> | 2013-01 | B     |
> | 2013-04 | C     |
> | 2014-06 | D     |
> +---------+-------+
> ```

How can I sort this data frame?

I tried to use: df.sort(['Date']). but it does not work.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: First, can you show us the actual data in your `DataFrame`, not just its `str` representation? In particular, is that a date column, or a string column?

Comment: Second, what does "it does not work" mean? It sorts in the wrong order? It raises an exception? (If so, paste the full exception, with traceback.) It gave you a sorted copy when you wanted an in-place sort? Or… what?

Comment: At any rate, when I try to guess at your actual data and build something that will print the same way as your `DateFrame`, then print out `df.sort(['Date'])`, I get the rows in order B, C, A, D, which seems to be exactly what you want. (Or maybe it's the reverse of what you want; you weren't clear what your expected output is—but in that case it's just a matter of `ascending=False`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following abarnet's comment using `df.sort` would solve the issue. You will have to use `inplace=True` in order for the dataframe to be sorted inplace. See the following as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dates = [datetime(2013, 12, 1), 
         datetime(2013, 1, 1), 
         datetime(2013, 4, 1),
         datetime(2012, 6, 1)]

val = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.Series(dates), 'value':pd.Series(val)})

df
Out[2]: 
       dates value
0 2013-12-01     A
1 2013-01-01     B
2 2013-04-01     C
3 2012-06-01     D

df.sort(['dates'], inplace=True)

df
Out[4]: 
       dates value
3 2012-06-01     D
1 2013-01-01     B
2 2013-04-01     C
0 2013-12-01     A
```